# This clause cannot match because a previous clause always matches

Tags: elixir

Not sure why I am getting this compiler warning. What am I doing wrong here?

```
defmodule T do
    def get_length do
        with {:ok, file} <- File.read("<file>"),
             content <- String.downcase(file) do
                IO.puts content
             end
    end
end
```

warning: this clause cannot match because a previous clause at line 4 always matches

Comment: Line 4 of the file isn't going to be the same as line 4 of this code snippet - could you either put appropriate line numbers or post the entire file?

Comment: Hi @CodyPoll. Updated.

Comment: FYI, I don't get the warning if I run this in Elixir shell. However if I run from the command line then I do.

Comment: I _do_ get the warning in iex (which is what I assume you mean by "Elixir shell").

Comment: Yes I mean iex. Really? I don't I am using version 1.2.4

Comment: My result {:module, T,
 <<70, 79, 82, , ...>>,
 {:get_length, 0}}
iex(9)> T.get_length
msft
xrx
:ok

Comment: FWIW @theKing yes I was seeing that message in iex on 1.2.4.I don't know why you _wouldn't_ see the message in iex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TLDR: `with` here is overkill.

```
defmodule T do
  def get_length do
    {:ok, file} = File.read("<file>") 
    IO.puts String.downcase(file)
  end
end
```

Also, you're getting the compiler warning because `content` would effectively match anything provided by `String.downcase/1`.

Verbose mode:

I don't think you understand the intent of `with`. `with` is sugar for chaining together a number of gnarly-nested cases by describing pattern matching on the happy path you care about.

So instead of having to write something heinous like this...

```
defp serve(socket) do
  msg =
    case read_line(socket) do
      {:ok, data} ->
        case KVServer.Command.parse(data) do
          {:ok, command} ->
            KVServer.Command.run(command)
          {:error, _} = err ->
            err
        end
      {:error, _} = err ->
        err
    end

  write_line(socket, msg)
  serve(socket)
end
```

...you can write this lovely magic:

```
defp serve(socket) do
  msg =
    with {:ok, data} <- read_line(socket),
         {:ok, command} <- KVServer.Command.parse(data),
         do: KVServer.Command.run(command)

  write_line(socket, msg)
  serve(socket)
end
```

So for fun, let's make up a situation where we could make use of `with` given your file example.

Imagine the functions defined here have fairly complex failure cases

```
defmodule X do
  def extract_header(file) do
    # returns {:ok, file} or {:err, file} or whatever
  end

  def starts_with_emoji?(file) do
    # returns true or false
  end
end
```

You can see how `with` can come in handy:

```
defmodule T do
  def header_emoji_alert do
    with {:ok, file} <- File.read("<file>"),
         {:ok, header} <- X.extract_header(file),
         true  <- X.starts_with_emoji?(header), do: IO.puts("EMOJI!!!!")
  end
end
```

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to tell what his (indefinite pronoun sense) intent is here.

Comment: Yes I did presented a simple case. And I know it is with a one happy path. My goal was to get used to using with since I like its fluency. So am I getting the compiler warning because I am using it only for a happy path?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It makes sense. I was just thrown off by the  warning.

Comment: The compiler warning is spot on: patterns are supposed to match a subset of possible values. `content <- String.downcase(whatever)` matches anything you provided it since content is undefined. Since the match isn't serving its purpose, you get an error.

Answer (score 3):

Did you actually mean to do this?

```
defmodule T do
   def get_length do
     with {:ok, file} <- File.read("<file>") do
       content = String.downcase(file) #Assigning result of String.downcase  will _always_ work.
       IO.puts content
     end
   end
 end
```

It's honestly a bit hard to infer the intent of your code.  I mean this would also do the same thing (as far as I can tell)

```
defmodule T do
   def get_length do
     {:ok, file} = File.read("<file>") 
     content = String.downcase(file)
     IO.puts content
   end
 end
```

I mean to say I'm not sure where using the `with` is gaining you anything here.

It's idiomatic in Erlang and Elixir to let the error get thrown that you'll get if you get back anything other than an `{:ok, file}` tuple from File.read.  If you can't read the file then there's not really a recovery option is there?